# Convert Neoload script to LoadRunner script

Tags: migration, performance-testing, loadrunner, neoload

Is there a tool which can convert Neoload projects or scripts to LoadRUnner scripts?

I found of lot of things on opposite and Neoload supporting convert from LoadRunner to NeoLoad but not opposite

Looking for options to conver bunch of scripts written in Neoload to Loadrunner , trying to avoid  to make this a big migration project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a tool, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proxy recorder.  Replay the Neoload script as an external application through the LoadRunner proxy recorder and you will have a record of all of the requests.

Youw will still need to go in and handle parameterization, correlation, pacing, etc...

Scripts have a limited life in any case.  The natural time to convert is when the limited life of a script expires and you are in a redevelopment mode anyway.  Use that opportunity to redevelop in LoadRunner, with insight on where and when to correlate/parameterize and pacing drawn from Neoload insight.

The inverse is also true.  If you are going from LoadRunner to Neoload, then when the limited life of your LoadRunner script expires, handle the redevelopment inside of Neoload.  Use your LoadRunner script is a guide for where and when you need to handle dynamic data, to parameterize, to pace.